# Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js

Just migrated a site of mine to different hosts and now a couple of Wordpress plugins not working. When selecting them on the back end the screen hangs. When I look at console I get the following errors -

Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function
53757 vue-router.esm.js:2671
Webpack 13
vue-router.esm.js:2671:13
53757 vue-router.esm.js:2671
Webpack 13

This happens on multiple plugins from different developers. The support team at the new hosts can't help. My first thought was it was Vue not being queued properly but I can't seem to see any issues with this. Any other thoughts on this would be massively appreciated. Wordpress isn't throwing any other errors and nothing else in console. All PHP parameters are the same as on the old servers.

I've tried clearing all caches, reinstalling all plugins. I've tried adding Vue from a CDN in different positions on the site. Nothing has cleared the errors.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins? And also, have you tried switching to a different theme?

Also, what changes did you make when you migrated to new host?